# Initializing a Class with varying arguments and varying parameters in Python

Tags: python

So I basically wanted to run a class but have the initialization vary depending on the amount of arguments I've provided.

Currently the class is run as such,

```
def __init__(self, *args): 
    if len(*args)==4:
        x=args[0]
        y=args[1]
        v=args[2]
        t=args[-1]
    if len(*args)==2:
        vx=args[0]
        vy=args[-1]
    if len(*args)==3:
        vx=args[0]
        vy=args[1]
        theta=args[-1]

    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.v=v
    self.t=t
    self.vx=vx
    self.vy=vy
    self.theta=theta
```

However, len(*args) only takes a single positional arguments and if I input Class(x,y,t,v) it won't run. I'd like to know the way I should start the initialization so I can have varying parameters.

I'm not supposed to split the class, according to the assignment given.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can use named args with default values; however, I am not sure your question is precise enough.

Comment: I have 3 cases: 
A user can input 2 arguments, both of which are floats or integers.
A user inputs 2 arguments, the first being an array and the second being a float.
A user inputs 4 arguments.

I'd like to contain all of these possibilities in one class. The problem has become that my args with default values limit my ability to handle the 2 argument case as it  args[2] is outside of the range of the index.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `*args` with `args` in the if statements

```
if len(args)==3:
```

`*args` is a bit of a place holder, `args` is the actual tuple you care about